# AWS S3 Cross Region Replication - When there is outage

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

We have a primary bucket that stores a list of files and a replication bucket in a different region. what will happen when the region that has replication bucket is down(has outage)

Will the replication fail or will it stay on pending state until the region is back?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let me quote the documentation:

> If object replication fails after you upload an object, you can't retry replication. You must upload the object again. Objects transition to a `FAILED` state for issues such as missing replication role permissions, AWS KMS permissions, or bucket permissions. **For temporary failures, such as if a bucket or Region is unavailable, replication status will not transition to `FAILED`, but will remain `PENDING`. After the resource is back online, S3 will resume replicating those objects.**

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/replication-status.html

Comment: I was onto the same thought, but replication within 15 minutes actually triggered an query. Thanks for pointing out the documentation.

Comment: Just a quick question to understand onto the same line, if the outage extends to be few hours also this applies right? That will still be in Pending state, right?

Comment: Until the status is PENDING is will be replicated some time later. But if it become FAILED, than you will need to act on it.

Answer (score 3):

Usually objects `replicate within 15 minutes`, however sometimes this can vary to hours depending on object size, including source and destination Region pair and outage like you mentioned.

so if your configuration in the source bucket is correct then i think that **will be in a pending state**, if its fails then you might need to check your source configuration over [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/replication-troubleshoot.html)

*FAILED is a terminal state that occurs only due to permission failures or misconfiguration (such as recreation of the destination bucket without versioning). It will not occur for transient issues* [source](https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?messageID=617951)